# Slow fulltext query when migrating from Mysql 5.7 to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have an issue with fulltext search when migrating from MySQL 5.7 to MariaDB 10.6.
In MariaDB it is a lot slower - taking up to 10 seconds when the same query takes 0.15 in MySQL.

The query is the following:

```
SELECT `products`.*, 
        MATCH (`products_search`.`distid`, `products_search`.`distCode`, `products_search`.`description`, 
               `products_search`.`namedist`,`products_search`.`name`, `products_search`.`vendor`, 
               `products_search`.`model`,`products_search`.`shortdesc`, `products_search`.`name_emag` )
        AGAINST ( ' memory* card*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS `score` 
FROM `products_search` 
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `products_search`.`id` 
WHERE MATCH (`products_search`.`distid`, `products_search`.`distCode`, `products_search`.`description`, 
             `products_search`.`namedist`, `products_search`.`name`, `products_search`.`vendor`, 
             `products_search`.`model`, `products_search`.`shortdesc`, `products_search`.`name_emag` ) 
      AGAINST ( ' memory* card*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0 
AND `products`.`instock` > 0 
AND `products`.`delivery` = 0 
AND `products`.`enabled`=1 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 20
```

EXPLAIN on MySQL says:
Using where; Ft_hints: sorted, rank > 0
Using where

EXPLAIN on MariaDB gives:
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
Using where

MariaDB> SHOW CREATE TABLE `products_search`:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_search` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `distid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `distCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `distributor` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(13) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `namedist` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name_emag` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'name for emag',
  `model` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'модел на продукта',
  `shortdesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `instock` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `delivery` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '0-налично, 100-на път, 1000-с поръчка',
  `limitedQty` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `category` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `vendor` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  KEY `distCode` (`distCode`),
  KEY `vendor_index` (`vendor`),
  KEY `name_index` (`name`) COMMENT 'name index',
  KEY `namedist-index` (`namedist`),
  KEY `ean` (`ean`),
  KEY `model_btree` (`model`) USING BTREE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_multicol` (`name`,`namedist`,`distCode`,`distid`,`description`,`model`,`shortdesc`,`vendor`,`name_emag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=395467 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci
```

MariaDB ANALYZE:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN7RK.png

MySQL 5.7 EXPLAIN EXTENDED:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORGmy.png

How can I fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: I've edited the original post and show create and analyze are there.

Comment: What does the 5.7 `EXPLAIN` say?  How many rows of `products_search` match "memory card"?  How many rows in `products_search`?

Comment: I've edited the original again, and the EXPLAIN EXTENDED of MySQL 5.7 is added. Analyze is not supported by MySQL 5.7.

Comment: I've written this up as [MariaDB Feature Request MDEV-32998 Slow fulltext query when migrating from Mysql 5.7 to MariaDB](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32998)

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE products; for more detailed analysis and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "products"; .  Thanks for other data already posted.

Comment: @IlianNikolov Ilian, Could you post from MDB the SCT and STS requested Dec 26, 2023 at 12:36?

Comment: @IlianNikolov Ilian, Could you post the QUERY from your 5.7 instance, please.  I suspect it is different than the version posted from MDB.  I suspect the hint of 5.7 is missing in the MDB version.